# How to let Open Policy Agent control global rate limit in Envoy proxy

Tags: rate-limiting, envoyproxy, open-policy-agent

I want to use Envoy proxy to globally limit number of HTTP requests per unit of time to my service.

Every server will host my service instance, an Envoy instance filtering traffic to service and an Open Policy Agent instance used to control rate limiting.
I also have a global rate limiting service using Redis.

I want Envoy to:

1. receive the HTTP request (works)
2. pass it Open Policy Agent to provide request limiting threshold by attaching additional headers to request like x-user: bob, x-rate-limit: 10, x-rate-limit-unit: m (works)
3. extract the values from these headers and pass them as
   gRPC envoy.service.ratelimit.v3.RateLimitRequest

{
"domain": "envoy",
"descriptors" : [{"entries": [{"key": "x-user", "value": ]},
"limit": "requests_per_unit": {},
"unit": {}]}]
to global rate limit service.

Is it possible with Envoy configuration of https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/rate_limit_filter ???
}

Comment: The use-case you're describing here is indeed covered by this filter. There are examples here: [envoy config](https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit/blob/59565c8730687f012b93bf551c7f2a427fd6a19f/examples/envoy/proxy.yaml), and [the ratelimiter (grpc service) config](https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit/blob/59565c8730687f012b93bf551c7f2a427fd6a19f/examples/ratelimit/config/example.yaml). If you're impementing your own rate limiting service, that's fine too, you can take example on the generic envoy ratelimiter service.